# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have been trying to fix this issue from so long time and pretty much game up as I couldn't find a way.

### Error from Java project

### Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

I followed this very well explained article: http://itbloggertips.com/2013/11/fixed-ora-01033-oracle-initialization-shutdown-progress/  to fix the issue. however, still facing issues.

### SqlPlus

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Apr 14 00:30:45 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: / as sysdba

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select status, database_status from v$instance;

STATUS       DATABASE_STATUS

---

MOUNTED      ACTIVE

SQL> select open_mode from v$database;

### OPEN_MODE

MOUNTED

SQL> select open_mode from v$database;

### OPEN_MODE

MOUNTED

SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 1 of thread 1
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\XXX\REDO01.LOG'
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 2) The system cannot find the file specified.

SQL>

--

Please suggest me.

Comment: try this....https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/2134811

Comment: the message is pretty straightforward, your pfile/spfile points to a controlfile that has that missing REDO01.LOG as part of it's assets. Either that file is missing or you are starting up your database with and old/different pfile/spfile. Regards